# How to add share in whatsapp image function in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am working on a wordpress site similar to [this](https://funkylife.in/girls-attitude-status-hindi/). I want same features like download button under each image, direct share in whatsapp and copy to clipbord functionalities. Can you any one please suggest? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the source code of the page sharethis appears often.
See if this provider already helps you. This should be here: https://sharethis.com/platform/wordpress-social-buttons/

You can download a plugin there. Probably the plugin is "SHARE BUTTONS".